# How to sort java List<Map<String, Object>> by String asc?

Tags: java

My java code is this:

```
List<SysUser> sysUserDeleteDuplicate = new ArrayList<SysUser>(new HashSet<SysUser>(sysUser));
List<Map<String, Object>> rList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
if(sysUserDeleteDuplicate!=null && sysUserDeleteDuplicate.size()>0){
    for (int i=0; i<sysUserDeleteDuplicate.size(); i++){
        Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        resultMap.put("text", sysUserDeleteDuplicate.get(i).getRealname());
        resultMap.put("value", sysUserDeleteDuplicate.get(i).getId());
        rList.add(resultMap);
    }
}
```

I want to sort elements in `rList` by `String` ascending.
And the data in rList likes this:

```
[{text=peter,value=1001},{text=lucy,value=1004},{text=kate,value=1002}]
```

I want this result:

```
[{text=kate,value=1002},{text=lucy,value=1004},{text=peter,value=1001}]
```

Comment: Do you need the map for a certain purpose? If not you should consider to refactor your code so that you use a new object instead of the map for rList containing the fields value and text. It will most likely improve readability for future development.

Comment: @BeWu Yes,now we need to use map.The developer of the web page ask to return the map structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make a custom comparator (some sorting criteria) for this. Something like:

```
Collections.sort(rListMap, new Comparator<Map<String, Comparable>> () {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, Comparable> a1, Map<String, Comparable> a2) {
        return a2.get(someThing).compareTo(a1.get(someThing));
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi,in fact,the Object is String type in my rList.

Answer (score 3):

As each list element is a `Map` potentially containing more than one instance of `Object`, you first need to re-define your sort criteria.

It would work if you say that you want to sort the list by the greatest `Object` in the `Map`.

But as `java.lang.Object` does not define `java.lang.Comparable<Object>`, there is no *natural order* for instances of `Object`. So you need to define a sorting criteria for `Object`, too. As there are not that many attributes, only the hash code or the result of `Object.toString()` would work.

With these informations, you can implement a `Comparator` that can be used as argument to `List.sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Shubham and tquadrat said,I modified `List<Map<String, Object>>` to
`List<Map<String, String>>`
I use this code:

```
List<SysUser> sysUserDeleteDuplicate = new ArrayList<SysUser>(new HashSet<SysUser>(sysUser));
List<Map<String, String>> rList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
if(sysUserDeleteDuplicate!=null && sysUserDeleteDuplicate.size()>0){
    for (int i=0; i<sysUserDeleteDuplicate.size(); i++){
        Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        resultMap.put("text", sysUserDeleteDuplicate.get(i).getRealname());
        resultMap.put("value", sysUserDeleteDuplicate.get(i).getId());
        rList.add(resultMap);
    }
}
Collections.sort(rList, new Comparator<Map<String, String>> () {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, String> a1, Map<String, String> a2) {
         return a1.get("text").compareTo(a2.get("text"));
         }
        });
System.out.println(rList.toString());
```

output:

```
[{text=kate, value=1002}, {text=lucy, value=1004}, {text=peter, value=1001}]
```